# OWASP CSRF Token Hijacking Fix

Tags: csrf, owasp

Could someone please help me understand why OWASP had to make this change to their reference implementation

https://github.com/aramrami/OWASP-CSRFGuard/commit/a494d4d7d7e9814fa0feaabf81f8264d10165ffb

The only hint in that commit is "The token is now removed and fetched using another POST request to solve,the token hijacking problem."

I would very much appreciate if someone could explain how this change prevents token hijacking.

Answer (score 0):

There are several changes in this commit, mostly if you look like it honors the configuration to protect or not protect forms that use `method="get"` (which is the default if bot specified as `post`.  There also appears to be some XHR(Ajax) related changes to populate the HTTP headers in the request differently from the config values.